# Missing information of copyright/licenses in debian binaries

Tags: ros, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have installed ROS and its packages using apt-get. I am interested to know the licenses of each package. I know that once option is to go to the wiki page of each package and check the licenses. But that could be a time taking process. I would like to know if there is way to find out the license information just from the debian files installed on my system.

After a few google searches I found that license/copyright information of any installed debian binary can be found at location
/usr/share/doc/XXXX/copyright . But I did not find any copyright file for any of the ROS debian binaries. For instance,  at the location ' /usr/share/doc/ros-hydro-roscpp ', there is only changelog.Debian and no copyright file.  I also checked the file /var/lib/dpkg/info/ros-hydro-roscpp.list, it did not mention about any copyright file.

I have the following question:

1. What would be the best way of finding the copyright/license of all the packages installed using apt-get ?
2. Does ROS plans to add copyright information file to the debian binaires which be available when installed through apt-get ?

Thanks in advance for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126681/missing-information-of-copyright/licenses-in-debian-binaries/) by [ss_robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/348/ss_robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-02-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The choice of license is available in the package.xml, which is availble in /opt/ros/hydro/share/package_name/package.xml.

The core ROS code is BSD license, as are many of the higher level packages that came out of Willow Garage (navigation, MoveIt). The notable exceptions to the BSD license are some of the libraries wrapped in (for instance, KDL is LGPL), and a few applications (slam_gmapping is actually Creative Commons non-commerical).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ss_robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/348/ss_robotics/) on 2014-02-13**:
Thanks a lot for such a quick response. I was not aware package.xml was copied to my system even when I install using apt-get. Now I am able to get the licenses information of the packages installed on my system.